# javascript access function from another namespace in namespaced ajax functions callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-namespaces

I need some help with my javascript code. I just recently started using namespaces and I have a problem which I am not able to solve.

I have two files **data.js** and **themes.js** with a namespace on each data and themes respectively.
On data namespace I have a function to perform an ajax call like this:

```
var data = data || {};data = {
    get_companies: function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            //blah blah blah
        });
    }
}
```

and in the themes namespace i have a function like this:

```
var themes = themes || {};
themes = {
    themeAdd: function () {
    //blah blah
        $.ajax({
            //blah blah
            success: function (data) {
                data.get_companies('#someid');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, while I can access `data.get_companies` from **themes.js** file and console, when I try to call it inside ajax callback it produces an error (data.get_companies is not a function). How can I fix that and why I can't access this function in ajax callbacks?

Comment: first place your  themes.js and then data.js , let see ? Hierachy matter

Comment: English is not my main language but i load them like that :<script src="public/history2/data.js"></script>
<script src="public/history2/theme.js"></script> if thats what you mean.Also those two attach to click handlers so they are both loaded on call time

Comment: Got it - change it then try

Comment: `var data = data || {}; data = {` makes no sense. As soon you do `data = {` you're out of game, making `data = data || {};` absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax `success` callback change the name of the argument passed to it:

```
$.ajax({
    //blah blah
    success: function (response) {
        data.get_companies('#someid');
    }
};
```

At the moment you define an anonymous function with an arument called `data`, so inside this function `data` is what has been received by AJAX request, not your global `data` object.

You could also try to access it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    //blah blah
    success: function (data) {
        window.data.get_companies('#someid');
    }
};
```

Comment: works like charm!!!To understand better this is caused by naming collision between ajax argument and namespace??